# Character set 'utf-8' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file

Tags: mediawiki, mysql, backups

We are trying to upgrade our MediaWiki software. According to [Manual:Upgrading](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading) -> [UPGRADE](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/MW/browse/REL1_27/UPGRADE) -> [Manual:Backing_up_a_wiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Backing_up_a_wiki), we are supposed to backup the database with:

```
mysqldump -h hostname -u userid -p --default-character-set=whatever dbname > backup.sql
```

When we run the command with our parameters and `--default-character-set=utf-8`:

```
$ sudo mysqldump -h localhost -u XXX -p YYY --default-character-set=utf-8 ZZZ > 
backup.sql
mysqldump: Character set 'utf-8' is not a compiled character set and is not spec
ified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file
```

Checking `Index.xml` appears to show `utf-8` is available. `UTF-8` is specifically called out by [Manual:$wgDBTableOptions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDBTableOptions).

```
$ cat /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml | grep -B 3 -i 'utf-8'
...
<charset name="utf8">
  <family>Unicode</family>
  <description>UTF-8 Unicode</description>
  <alias>utf-8</alias>
...
```

We tried both `UTF-8` and `utf-8` as specified by [Manual:$wgDBTableOptions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDBTableOptions).

I have a couple of questions. First, can we omit `--default-character-set` since its not working as expected? Second, if we have to use `--default-character-set`, then what is used to specify `UTF-8`?

---

A third, related question is, can we forgo `mysqldump` all-together by taking the wiki and database offline and then making a physical copy of the database? I am happy to make a copy of the physical database for a restore; and I really don't care much for using tools that cause more trouble than they solve.

If the third item is a viable option, then what is the physical database file that needs to be copied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First, can we omit --default-character-set since its not working as expected?

We took the first option and the upgrade proceeded. You mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:

```
ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
mysqld: Character set 'UTF-8' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file
mysqld: Character set 'UTF-8' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file
```

I edited the mysqld.cnf and changed

```
character-set-server = UTF8
```

to

```
character-set-server = utf8mb4
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case It was the same command but I did not need to change the conf file, and the command `--default-character-set` indeed does work. It is a bug with MySQL, just change "utf-8" to "utf8" or even "utf8mb4" for MySQL.